# Outlook Automatic Replies when OOO in Clendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, automation, out-of-office

Is there a way that you can set outlook to send automatic replies if your calendar has an "Out of Office" set in your calendar?

Answer (score 0):

You can send Out of Office responses by setting it up as described [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-automatic-out-of-office-replies-from-outlook-9742f476-5348-4f9f-997f-5e208513bd67).

Otherwise the Calendar does not send Out of Office responses. Extract of a query from this [question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/can-i-set-out-of-office-messages-based-on-outlook/d2c901c2-b153-48fb-8366-e0521f595d38):

> Do you know if there is a way that I can send it as a feature
>   request? I've run it by 2 IT guys here and a few friends, and they
>   100% agree it would be a brilliant addition to Outlook (unless it's
>   just that we don't know how to get it to work!)

Comment: Bummer, that would really help as I always have to setup reminders to turn on my OOO replies.

Comment: I understand but as per above, you cannot.

Comment: You can only turn on your OOO manually when you are away.

Comment: Thanks all, appreciate it.

Comment: Now you know the answer, you might consider closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am a bit late, but the other questions like this had already been answered (with outdated answers).

If you have access to Power Automate, you can create a flow to automate the described process. I cannot share a link to the flow I created, but I can provide a screenshot and all the expressions, so you can create it yourself.

---

**New method where you create the flow yourself**

[Link to the screenshot of the flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMY5a.png)

When an upcoming event is starting soon (V3), that is OoO -> Settings -> Trigger Conditions

```
@equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/showAs'], 'oof')
```

Stop if user already OoO

```
outputs('Get_mail_tips_for_a_mailbox_(V2)')?['body/value']?[0]?['automaticReplies/message']
```

Set up automatic replies (V2)

```
formatDateTime(triggerOutputs()?['body/end'],'dddd, MMMM d')
```

---

**Old method with the flow exported as zip.**

1. Download [this zip](https://www.mediafire.com/file/t0cltovtp512ofm/OutlookAutomaticReplieswhenOOOinClendar_20220718131451.zip/file).
2. Open [Power Automate](https://make.powerautomate.com/flows) -> My Flows -> Import -> Import Package. ([Image of the menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tad3n.png))
3. Select the zip you downloaded in step 1.
4. Click **Select during import** and select your Outlook account on the right.
5. If no account appears, click **Create new** -> **New connection** -> search **Office 365 Outlook**, hit create and sign in.
6. After an account has been selected, click **Import**.
7. Wait for the import and click **Open flow** to edit the flow.
8. Edit the last step in the flow **Set up automatic replies (V2)** to your preferences.

Comment: Welcome to SU, and thanks for your answer! Can you modify the first step to only use downloads from official sources (in this case MS) or replace it with the Power Automate signup process? Random Mediafire downloads should be avoided. Thanks :)